# How to update a counter or multiple counters in a single transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My model has a few counters on it, and I want to increment/decrement these counters, and they should be done in a transaction.

So for example, the `User` model has  `sales_count`, `friend_count`.

Now I want to modify both of them in a transaction:

```
user.sales_count += 1
user.friend_count += 3
user.save
```

**How can I do this in a transaction?**

I know there is increment_counter, but that seems to be for only a single attribute and I can't figure out how to add 2 or subtract 2 instead of just 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `update_counters`

```
User.update_counters(user_id, :sales_count => 1, :friend_count => 3, :other_count => -2)
```

Comment: how about if I wanted to add 2 column values together?  (not the model in memory but at teh database level like:  :counter3 => :counter1 + :counter2  (that doesnt' work but I want it to!)

Comment: I don't think there is a method that can do what you want. You could take a look at the source code of the `update_counters` method to see how it is done (basically just generating SQL dynamically): http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/update_counters

Comment: for those reading in future don't forget to add the caching to true in the relevant models